# Android JAVA Cannot connect MYSQL DB JDBC

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

android cannot connect MYSQL server

Error Note:

```
04-11 04:01:51.283: W/System.err(913): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
04-11 04:01:51.296: W/System.err(913): The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
04-11 04:01:51.296: W/System.err(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-11 04:01:51.304: W/System.err(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
```

MYSQL-DB Connection Code

```
private String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.10:8090/test";
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private java.sql.Statement stmt; 
    private java.sql.Connection conn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e(TAG, "step 1");
    try {
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            Log.e(TAG, "step 2");
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error 1");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error 2");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error 3");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {Log.e(TAG, "step 3");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, user, pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error 4");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {Log.e(TAG, "step 4");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {Log.e(TAG, "error 5");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
```

Comment: 192.168.2.10 is a private ip address so is the android on the same subnet?

Comment: refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: i renamed actual ip address

Comment: my systemipaddress:portno

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply @karthik i am trying db connect from android application. thread which refered is java

Comment: @Bharanikumar But your question is basically the same; however you should ask yourself if you really should connect directly from an Android tablet/phone to MySQL directly.

Comment: in my post title i mentioned android, there is difference connecting from android java and just java. as well, first time i am trying this mysql connect from android code. i started this exercise with the reference of some other threads only.